# Excel vba pastespecial not working

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I'm trying to transpose links in excel and I'm writing a macro for this purpose. The only problem I have is that the pastespecial option is not working.

```
Sub Transpose_Links()
'
' Transpose_Links Macro
'
' Hotkey: Ctrl+m
'
```

I have the cells I want to transpose on my clipboard at this moment
I then paste them to the current location. They can then be altered
so the links remain in the content of the cells

```
Sheets("wincc").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True
Selection.Replace What:="=", Replacement:="xxx", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = True
Selection.Cut
```

After cutting the altered information again I want to ask for a range                       where to paste them
This succeeds because I already tried altering the values of the range and it worked. I also tried using regular Paste but this also didn't work. I tried searching the site for similar problems, but I didn't find one. I also checked the method on msdn.microsoft.com but I didn't give much information.

```
Dim rRange As Range
Set rRange = Application.InputBox(Prompt:= _
            "Please select a range with your Mouse to be bolded.", _
                Title:="SPECIFY RANGE", Type:=8)
rRange.PasteSpecial Paste = xlPasteAll, Operation = xlNone, SkipBlanks = _
    False, Transpose:=True
rRange.Replace What:="xxx", Replacement:="=", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub Transpose_Links()
Dim rRange As Range

' Transpose_Links Macro
'
' Hotkey: Ctrl+m
'

Sheets("wincc").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True

Selection.Replace What:="=", Replacement:="xxx", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = True
Selection.Cut


Set rRange = Application.InputBox(Prompt:= _
            "Please select a range with your Mouse to be bolded.", _
                Title:="SPECIFY RANGE", Type:=8)

Selection.Copy
rRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True


rRange.Replace What:="xxx", Replacement:="=", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, I implemented your help.

Comment: But i got error 1004: method pastespecial from class range has failed, am I still doing something wrong? With the previous comment I accidentally pressed enter..

Comment: As far as i understand of your code, you have first to copy the range manually and then run the code.

Comment: Yea, I copy it manually from another worksheet and then I want to run the code and paste it in the range I selected

Comment: the code works for me: First i copy manually, then i run the code, I select the range.

Comment: Of course you cannot select the range where the links are paste in the first time

Comment: I know what I did wrong, I didn't declare the variable rRange at the start as you did.. Thanks!

Comment: When you select the range the cells are empty?

Comment: Sorry I can't chat btw. If you mean for the range of the input box, yea initially they are empty, but now it even works for non-empty cells